# How to combine two Data Frames of different sizes?

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to combine two data frames.
here is my data frames

df1=

```
id  effectiveDate    value
 1  2019-01-01         0.1
 1  2019-01-02         0.2
```

df2=

```
id name
 1   abc
```

i want my final data frame look like
df=

```
id name  column3
 1  abc  2019-01-01, 2019-01-02, 0.1, 0.2
```

but what im getting is

df=

```
id  name effectiveDate value
 1   abc  2019-01-01     0.1
 1   abc  2019-01-02     0.2
```

Comment: Please include the code that you tried.

Comment: I do not know how to format the question

Comment: Furthermore, the result you are getting seems a much better way of storing your data then what you intend to do. With the way you want it, you will lose information.

Comment: Maybe `aggregate(.~id + name, merge(df1, df2), toString)` ?

Comment: Please include a reproducible  form (in R) of your data. Can be done with `dput(df)`...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr` to accomplish it:

```
library(dplyr)

df2 %>% 
  left_join(df1, by = "id") %>% 
  group_by(id, name) %>% 
  summarise(column3 = paste(toString(effectiveDate), toString(value), sep = ", ")) 

## A tibble: 1 x 3
## Groups:   id [1]
#id name  column3                        
#  <int> <fct> <chr>                          
#1     1 abc   2019-01-01, 2019-01-02, 0.1, 0.2
```

If you want to avoid using groups, you can do:

```
df2 %>% 
  left_join(df1, by = "id") %>% 
  mutate(column3 = paste(toString(effectiveDate), toString(value), sep = ", ")) %>% 
  select(id, name, column3) %>% 
  distinct()

#  id name                         column3
#1  1  abc 2019-01-01, 2019-01-02, 0.1, 0.2
```

Comment: it works but column3 should be data frame for me .. In this case it says its character

Comment: In your OP `column3` is a column in a `data.frame`. I'm not clear, therefore, which is your expected output... Can you tell me how exactly your output would looks like?

Comment: my output should look like how you got it .. but  class(column3) is character its not data frame . if i print colum3 from the output it should give me dataframe

Comment: I don't know how familiar you're with R, but you can't store a `data.frame` inside a `data.frame`. You can convert it to a list and store column3 as a data.frame.